# How to add available custom skills to my virtual assistant?

Tags: botframework

How do I add custom skill to my Virtual Assistant?

Do I need to download the repo and build the solution from here https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-skills/tree/master/skills/csharp and deploy to my Azure environment?

I have been trying to follow documentation from https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/skills/tutorials/add-prebuilt-skill/1-intro/ but this documentation has not mentioned about which code to use anywhere. I tried building a solution using sample skill template in VS but that didn't work.

Comment: where are you exactly stuck at? The basic steps are Make VA bot -> Deploy VA bot -> create a skill -> deploy the skill -> redeploy VA. Refer to https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/skills/handbook/add-skills-to-a-virtual-assistant/ or https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/overview/skills/ or the prebuilt one which you have already linked.